# Session user not changing

Tags: php, session

I've managed to reflect the user who logged in into a form. However now when a new user logs in, the previous user personal particulars eg name is still reflecting on the form. This is what i have so far. What am i missing out?

```
$result2 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT admin_no FROM student_details;");
    $row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);

    ?>

<p>
<table border="1">
 <tr>
   <td width="410" align="center">Student Personal Data</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>


           </td>
         </tr>
             <tr>
             <td>Admission Number</td>
             <td><input name= "name" type="text" disabled="disabled" value="<?php echo $row2['admin_no'] ?>"
    size="40" readonly>
              </td>
         </tr>
```

This is how i my logout page looks like :

```
<?php

    session_start();
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();


    header('Location:login.php');


?>
```

My login page :

```
<? 
$adminName = $_POST['txtName'];
$adminPassword = $_POST['txtPassword'];

  $conn = dbConnect();
    if (!$conn)
        die("Couldn't connect to MySQL");

    $query = "select * from ohrm_user where user_name='$adminName' and user_password= '$adminPassword'";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $conn);
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);


    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0 && $row['user_role_id'] == 1)
    { 

  echo $_SESSION['user_name'] = $adminName;
  echo $_SESSION['user_password'] = $adminPassword;

} 

dbDisconnect($conn);
```

Comment: place session_start() as first line in login page...

Comment: `session_start();` needs to be inside `all` pages.

Comment: @Fred-ii- even logout?

Comment: Plus, I don't know you're mixing `mysqli_*` with `mysql_*` functions in seperate pages.

Comment: Yes, even in the logout page.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i did but it is still not working. cant figure out the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Insert session_start()

in first line of login and other control panel pages

look at this link

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp